# Different CSS background-image depending on month and year

Tags: php, css, date, background-image

Basically, I have a div with text in it, and I want the background to display a different image depending on what month and year it is.

How can I achieve this?
Any help would be greatly appriciated!

---

*I've prepared 4 years worth of monthly images labelled "month0_2011.png" to "month11_2014.png" already if that helps?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `.php` extension to the CSS and use PHP code to determine that. Just use standard PHP tags.

For example:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('<?php echo $currentImagePath ?>');
}
```

Where `$currentImagePath` is the path to your image, determined beforehand (i.e. top of page) using PHP.

```
$currentImagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/css/images/" . "month" . (date("n") - 1) . "_" . date("Y") . ".png";
```

Putting it all together:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
$currentImagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/css/images/" . "month" . (date("n") - 1) . "_" . date("Y") . ".png";
?>

body
{
    background-image:url('<?php echo $currentImagePath ?>');
}
```

All that is left is adjusting the path to fit your configuration.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using PHP? I don't see a [tag:php] tag.

Comment: I was assuming PHP was available since the OP did not state that it wasn't.

Comment: Apologies, the pages I'm styling are indeed .php. I'm completely self-taught so I go through by trial and error, I never realised style sheets could end in an extension other than .css.

Pardon my ignorance, but which bit of php code would I need to set up the currentImagePath echo to direct it to my files depending on the user's clock (month and year specifically)? And would the corresponding php code go in the css file or the page I want to style?

Many thanks; am very impressed with you all! Although I'm very familiar with html, css etc. I'm still at basic level with php.

Comment: I added the PHP code 10 minutes ago. :) Also, the extension can be .php or .css.php, as long as it ends in .php. The code should be in the stylesheet only.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, although I've changed my main.css file to end in the .php extension and then changed the source code in my file to this: `<link href="maincss.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` however the page is now not styling. Do I need to put something at the top of my new maincss.php file to tell it that it's still a style sheet? All the colour coding in my code editor has diappeared now too.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a header to the top. See my code again. And the text coloring loss is a downside, but you can rename the file to .css when editing it, and use .php when you upload it.

Comment: Thank you @Evan. It wasn't working for me for a while but it did when I removed `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . ` and the following `/` from the file root. It works now. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a script on the top of yout page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth(); 
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var backgroundpictture= "month" + month  + "_" + year + ".png";
document.body.background = backgroundpictture;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JavaScript/jQuery to get the date, month, and year from the user. Doing something like they do here: http://arnelbornales.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/get-the-current-date-using-jquery/ then using something like an `if` statement to determine which month and then change the source of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using a  bit of jQuery

```
var fullDate = new Date();
var month = fullDate.getMonth();
var year = fullDate.getFullYear();
var img = 'month' + month + '_' + year + '.png';

$('#monthly').css('backgroundImage', img);
```

Assuming your `div` is

```
<div id="monthly">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any javascript and special css treatment.. Use

```
<div style="background-image:url(images/bg-<?php echo date("Y"); ?>);">content</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After trawling for a solution that actually worked and was really simple to implement if found the script below. Simply copy and paste it into a .js file and link to it in your head tag:

```
var s = new Date();
 var month = s.getMonth();

switch (month)
{
case 0:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/january.css" />');
  break;
case 1:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/february.css" />');
  break;
case 2:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/march.css" />');
  break;
case 3:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/april.css" />');
  break;
case 4:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/may.css" />');
  break;  
case 5:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/june.css" />');
  break;
case 6:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/july.css" />');
  break;
case 7:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/august.css" />');
  break;
case 8:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/september.css" />');
  break;
case 9:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/october.css" />');
  break;
case 10:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/november.css" />');
  break;
case 11:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/december.css" />');
  break;  
default:
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://the-path/to-your/stylesheets/folder/style.css" />');
}
```