# How to Change CSS Dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need my administrator to be able to change/update the banner of my site.

This is the banner code

```
<div class="containertop">This depends on the background of the div</div>
```

and this is the CSS for that

```
.containertop
{
     width:1000px;
     height:300px;  
     **background:url(../images/1.png) no-repeat center;**
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 40px;
}
```

What I would like to happen is the same as a Facebook cover photo. 
When a new banner is uploaded, the CSS will be updated(something like that).
But of course, the new banner must be fetched from the database.

So I am thinking that the CSS would become like this:

Fetch the saved banner source and then:

```
background:url(<?php echo $row['image']; ?>);
```

but can I do the PHP connection to database (include 'dbname.php') inside a CSS txt?

Comment: You can dynamically change it using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: It would be easier to use inline css on the tag itself - move `background:url(../images/1.png) no-repeat center;` into the tag as a style element, then set that in PHP. No need for JS here.

Comment: http://www.coolphptools.com/dynamic_css check this

Comment: how can i do that? are there any tutorial links you can recommend?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927649/different-css-background-image-depending-on-month-and-year/6927665#6927665).

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful to you but there are some CSS frameworks out there to help do stuff like this.  Have a look at http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ben. If you make a little embedded css section in your page, you could put the .containerTop css code there. Then, put your code in the page.
So, in your actual web page, put this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.containertop{
width:1000px;
height:300px;  
background:url(<?php echo $row['image']; ?>);
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Of course, your background url will not update until it is reloaded. If you decide to do it this way, don't forget to take the .containerTop definition out of your existing css.
Having said all that, I really like dystroy's answer. Very nice. I never thought of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing preventing you to serve a css generated by PHP. That's even easy.

Simply start your php file like this :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

Comment: Nice.  Doing something like this had never occurred to me before.  I need to peruse SO more often (*throws in toolbox... wanders off in random direction*).

Answer (score 1):

You can set containertop background while loading php file.

```
<?php
echo "<style>.containertop{ background:url(../images/".$row['image'].") no-repeat center;}</style>"
?>
```

This will set the background fetched from db.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use jQuery to change/overwrite the CSS file.

Example -

```
$('.containertop').css('backgroud','url(images/change.jpg) repeat');
```

or

```
$('.containertop').css('backgroud','url(<?php echo $images_url ?>) repeat');
```